# Best way to store user location data with socket.io?

Tags: javascript, express, mobile, socket.io

I'm building a back-end for an app that uses socket.io and firebase to store messages and users. I need to use the user's location to in order to check if the server should push back a message to the user. I'm having trouble deciding how to implement this.

```
socket.on('connection', socket => {
   let location = {
      latitude: 0.0,
      longitude: 0.0
   }

   socket.on('incoming_location', data => {
   // Saves to the location variables'
   })
   
   // onSnapshot logic from firebase to check for new messages then checks if message adheres to the location variable then emits back to socket.
})
```

or would something else be better?

Comment: If all your socket handlers are inside that `connection` closure and the only code that needs access to the location is inside this closure, then this will work just fine.  Otherwise, you can add a property to the `socket` object itself such that you have `socket.location` and then any code anywhere that has access to the `socket` can get its location too.